# error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript

Tags: c++, c, arrays, parameter-passing, quicksort

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int t,n,k,m,i,j;
int l[100002],r[100002],c[100002],a[100002],total=0;
int swap( int *a, int *b)
{
    int temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
int pivot( int l, int h)
{
    int x=c[h],i=l,j=l-1,temp;
    for(i=l;i<h;i++)
    {
        if(c[i]<x)
        {
            j++;
            swap(&c[i],&c[j]);
            swap(&r[i],&r[j]);
            swap(&l[i],&l[j]);
        }
    }
    j++;
    swap(&c[h],&c[j]);
    swap(&l[h],&l[j+1]);
    swap(&r[h],&r[j+1]);
    return j;
}
int quick( int l, int h)
{
    int p;
    if(l<h)
    {
        p=pivot(l,h);
        quick(l,p-1);
        quick(p+1,h);
    }
}
int main() {
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        total=0;
        cin>>n>>k>>m;
        for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
            total+=a[i];
        }
        for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
            cin>>l[i]>>r[i]>>c[i];
        quick(1,m);
        for(i=1;i<=m;i++)
            cout<<l[i]<<r[i]<<c[i]<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code I am getting the following error.

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int pivot(int, int)':
prog.cpp:21:13: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
    swap(&l[i],&l[j]);
             ^
prog.cpp:21:19: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
    swap(&l[i],&l[j]);
                   ^
prog.cpp:26:11: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
  swap(&l[h],&l[j+1]);
           ^
prog.cpp:26:19: error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
  swap(&l[h],&l[j+1]);
                   ^
```

Can you figure out what the error is? And also I am wondering why I am getting this error only in array `l` not in `r` or `c`. So please explain this also.

Here is the link of the above program.

http://ideone.com/K1exEK

Comment: `i`, `1`, `l`,`I`, `|`, `j` - you just love your readers that much? :-)

Comment: Is this an obfuscated code-kinda challenge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`l` is the function parameter of type `int`, it hides the global variable with the same name.

Comment: Ohh man..what a silly mistake I've made...Though Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @AnujGarg you have name conflict with the names from `namespace std`. Remove `using namespace std;` from your code. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3959454)

Comment: So what actually is the use of using namespace std;

Comment: @AnujGarg This is way beyond the topic of this question. I believe you should read a [decent C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/3959454).